# Calculate output in Elasticsearch Dev tools

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

Using Elasticsearch 7.*, we have a field 'ElapsedTime' under the mapping and I am trying to write a query to generate output of that field as 'ElapsedTime' / 1000.
Tried below but no luck:

1)

```
GET /_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "params._source.ElapsedTime / 1000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. 

```
GET /_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test2": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "expression",
        "source": "doc['ElapsedTime'] / 1000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Errors:

1. null pointer exception
2. parse_exception: Field [ElapsedTime] does not exist in mappings

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `GET concrete-index/_search` on a `concrete-index` and not on `/` which runs on all indexes of your cluster, where the chance of hitting an index which doesn't have `ElapsedTime` in its mapping is quite big.

Comment: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [concrete-index]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "concrete-index",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "concrete-index"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [concrete-index]",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "concrete-index",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "concrete-index"
  },
  "status" : 404
}

Comment: You need to replace `concrete-index` with the actual name of your index, I don't know what it is

Comment: "com-att-csi-grm-test-aks-000054" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },       
        "ElapsedTime" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }

Comment: ElapsedTime mapping is as above, now I am trying to execute GET com-att-csi-grm-test-aks-000054/_mappings/properties/_search - its giving error as "error" : "no handler found for uri [/com-att-csi-grm-test-aks-000054/_mappings/properties/_search?pretty=true] and method [GET]"